# access to variables from different php blocks

Tags: php, html, variables

I need to write a large block of html from a php file. To do this, I am closing an initial php block (using '?>'), then writing the html, followed by the new php block.

I need to access variables from the first php block in the second php block.

Could anyone explain the most efficient way to do this?

Right now, when I refer, in the second block, to a variable assigned with a non-zero value in the first block, I just get a returned value of 0.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126261/php-variable-scope-between-code-blocks

Comment: The variable should still have a value in the next block. Show us some code.

Comment: @OrangeTux I think you should post this link as an answer.

Comment: Answer can be found here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126261/php-variable-scope-between-code-blocks

@pyrate :done

Comment: OK thanks all, your comments have let me understand the problem better. I will be using suggestion by Martins Briedis (below) to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look in to something like a MVC development pattern.

The easiest way would be not to output everything in many blocks, but to append to a certain variable which is echoed at the end.

```
// code block
$html .= '<strong>Some html</strong>';

// other code block
$html .= '...';

// Other code

// At last, at the end
echo $html;
```

Comment: Thanks, will be using this approach.