# How to define variable in PHP to be visible over whole html page?

Tags: php, html, global-variables

I have an html page with few `<?php ?>` code snippets in it. In the first snippet I am connecting to a database and fetching data. Now I want to display that data later in some `div` tags on my HTML page.

So, is the following the easiest way to do it? When I fetch the data from my database, I store them in an array which I define globally - I mean to be visible in other PHP code snippets on page, and then in those div tags I just print whatever elements of that array I want, like this: `<div class="info"> <?php print  "{$info[2]} ?> </div>`.  Is this the correct and safe way to do this and how it's done, I mean how should I define this global array `$info`?

Comment: That's the way it is generally done when using PHP as a templating language in the context of a single HTML page, yeah. You could make it an associative array so you know further down in the code which element is which

Comment: [PHP variable scope between code blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5126417/285587)

Answer (score 3):

use **global** keword:
global $variable_name;