# PHP PDO MySQL not executing simple insert command

Tags: php, html, mysql, backend

the PHP PDO MySQL is not working with the insert ... I am making a company application, the part I am working with, is the employers add and view part. This is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Employers page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header"><button class="menu" style="float:right;">menu</button></div>
    <div class="black" id="black"></div>
    <div id="side" style="background:white;"></div><br><br>

    <?php 
        $username = "root" ;
        $password = "" ;
        $database = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=company;charset=utf8;", $username, $password);
    ?>

    <center><form method="post" id="form">
        Select Action : <select name="action" id="action">
            <option value="viewAll">See all employers</option>
            <option value="viewSpecific">See defined group or employers</option>
            <option value="add">Add new Employers</option>
        </select><br><br>

        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Action</button>
    </form></center>
    <div>
        <center><form method="POST" id="addData" style="margin:3px;padding:1px;display:none;">
            <table id="employersAddTable">
                <tr><td>Name of Employer : </td><td><input type="text" name="nameEmployer"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Date of Work : </td><td><input type="date" name="dateEmployer"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Image of Employer : </td><td><input type="file" name="imageEmployer" accept="image/*"></td></tr>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" name="submitEmployer">Submit Data</button>
        </form></center>
    </div>

    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if($_POST['action'] == "add"){
                echo '<script>document.getElementById("addData").style.display = "inline-block"</script>' ;
                if(isset($_POST['submitEmployer'])){
                    $file = "data:".$_FILES["imageEmployer"]["type"].";base64,".file_get_contents($_FILES["imageEmployer"]["tmp_name"]);
                    $insert = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO `employees`(name,date,image) VALUES(:name, :date, :image);");
                    $insert->bindParam("name", $_POST["nameEmployer"]);
                    $insert->bindParam("date", $_POST["dateEmployer"]);
                    $insert->bindParam("image", $file);
                    $insert->execute();
                    if($insert->execute()) {
                        echo "<script>alert('Successfully command executed !')</script>" ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am new to the back-end developing. The problem is that the command in the `$insert` variable is not executed, I don't know why, tried `var_dump($insert->errorinfo())` but showing that there is no error, checked for the sql command but it is good syntax and it is executed, so the error is in this part :

```php
if(isset($_POST['submitEmployer'])){
                    $file = "data:".$_FILES["imageEmployer"]["type"].";base64,".file_get_contents($_FILES["imageEmployer"]["tmp_name"]);
                    $insert = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO `employees`(name,date,image) VALUES(:name, :date, :image);");
                    $insert->bindParam("name", $_POST["nameEmployer"]);
                    $insert->bindParam("date", $_POST["dateEmployer"]);
                    $insert->bindParam("image", $file);
                    $insert->execute();
                    if($insert->execute()) {
                        echo "<script>alert('Successfully command executed !')</script>" ;
                    }
                }
```

can anyone help me in this part ?????? thanks.

Comment: why here is if($_POST['action'] == "add") condition?

Comment: because There are two another pages I will add : view all employers and view only specific employers, the condition ```if($_POST['action'] == "add")``` is to say that I am in the **add employers** page

Comment: 1. there is no $_POST['action'] on this page. 2. There is already if(isset($_POST['submitEmployer'])). Why do you need that $_POST['action'] at all?

Comment: ```$_POST["action"]``` is the select element in the html page, second the ```$_POST['submitEmployer']``` is the submit of the **employers add** page

Comment: There are two **statements** in my last comment. It's not questions, you don't have to answer them. It's the information for you to learn from. There is only one question there but you didn't answer it.

Comment: the first condition : ```if(isset($_POST['submit']))``` is to detect what page I should use. After selecting the _Add New Employer_ page and click on _submit action_ an invisible form will appear. the next condition : ```if(isset($_POST['submitEmployer']))``` is for the page appeared, when _Submit data_ button is clicked, the data will be sent to the company database=>employees table. Good info ?

Comment: No. Bad logic. You already have if(isset($_POST['submitEmployer'])). You don't need any other condition. Not to mention that either $_POST['submit'] and $_POST['action'] **do not exist** on that page at all

Comment: THIS : **```<select name="action" id="action">```** isn't ```$_POST["action"]``` ???  or this : **```<button type="submit" name="submitEmployer">Submit Data</button>```** isn't ```$_POST["submitEmployers"]``` ???????????????? the benefit of them is selecting the page and sending the data to database. ```$_POST['submit']``` and ```$_POST['action']``` does **exist** on the page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126417

Comment: What.... You redirected me to the _Global Variables Problem In PHP_ but why ??

Comment: Because either $_POST['submit'] and $_POST['action'] do not exist on that page and you need to learn that

Comment: Read the upper code not the bottom one.. or what you mean ? where is the scope you are saying ??????